# How to add pagecurl effect to pdf in android

Tags: android, pdf, page-curl

I am making one book reader application in that I am using pdftron library everything working fine but right now I wanted to add pagecurl effect to documents of pdf ,I tried some samples from internet that all are related to imageview but I need pagecurl effect to pdfcontroller,is  there any pdf libraries that are providing pagecurl effect to pdf pages ,please reply

Comment: no i used harism page curl

Comment: It means you convert pdf to images then set curl effect on it?!

Answer (score 0):

PdFtron has no inbuilt support for curl effect as referred by this post

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pdfnet-sdk/LTBAf75heRA/cXnD2-j4vwgJ